# How can I stream test output when building a Haskell package with Nix?

Tags: haskell, cabal, nix, nix-hydra

I have a project built with Nix on Hydra. When the tests are run for it, it prints the logs to a file, which makes them hard to view from a CI server. Is there a way I can make the project print stdout/err as the test suite runs? This is what I currently get:

```
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite test: RUNNING...
Test suite test: FAIL
Test suite logged to: dist/test/project-name-0.0.0-test.log
0 of 1 test suites (0 of 1 test cases) passed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The `cabal new-run test:test` part is incorrect. I'm looking into how to get Nix's Haskell builder to stream test results.

You can override the `checkPhase` in Nix to accomplish this. You can see it defined here: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/32340793aafec24dcef95fee46a21e634dd63457/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/generic-builder.nix#L357-L361

This `checkPhase` should work:

```
checkPhase = ''
  runHook preCheck
  cabal new-run test:test
  runHook postCheck
'';
```